# How can I see time of day for creation or modification of file in google drive (when file is not created today)

Tags: google-drive

I created two files on the same day, with the same name, and similar content. I need to know which is which. I know the time that I created them.

They were created while teaching two separate classes, they are the record of how far I got with each class, I need to know which document is for which. I have the class time-table, so just need to match the creation time to the time-table.

Google drive does not seem to show time of day, for files that are older than (I guess 24 hours).

How can I see the full date, including time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not as simple as I would hope you can do the following work-around.

Open the file. Goto `menu` -> `file` -> `version` -> `version history`.
In this history you can see the precise time of creation.

Comment: I tried this solution on 8/15/23 and the menu has changed slightly:   click on menu (3 dots vertically aligned)  -> file information -> manage versions